# Strange issue when storing FFT periods in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, fft

I am trying to store the results of FFT calculations in a Pandas data frame:

```
ft = pd.DataFrame(index=range(90))
ft['y'] = ft.index.map(lambda x: np.sin(2*x))
ft['spectrum']  = np.fft.fft(ft['y'])
ft['freq']      = np.fft.fftfreq(len(ft.index)).real
ft['T']         = ft['freq'].apply(lambda f: 1/f if f != 0 else 0)
```

Everything seems to be working fine until the last line: the column T which is supposed to store periods has for some reason all the columns of the frame, ie.:

```
In [499]: ft.T[0]
Out[499]:
y                            0j
spectrum    (0.913756021471+0j)
freq                         0j
T                            0j
Name: 0, dtype: complex128
```

I cannot figure out why is that. It happens also when I only take the real part of freq:

```
ft['freq']  = np.fft.fftfreq(len(ft.index)).real
```

or I try to calculate T values using alternative ways, such as:

```
ft.T = ft.index.map(lambda i: 1/ft.freq[i] if ft.freq[i] else np.inf)
ft.T = 1/ft.freq
```

All other columns look tidy when I run `head()` or `describe()` on them no matter if they contain real or complex values. The freq column looks like a normal 1D series, because `np.fft.fftfreq()` returns 1D array of complex numbers, so what could be the reason why the column T is so messed up?

I am using Pandas v. 1.19.2 and Numpy v. 1.12.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `DataFrame` objects have [a property](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas-dataframe-t) called `T`, which is used "to transpose index and columns" of the DataFrame object. If you use a different column name instead of `T`, everything works as expected.

Comment: I knew it must have been something silly on my part :) Thanks for the quick response.