# How to loop through pandas dataframe ignoring Nan cells?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with some data stored in a column called "col1". To compute the minimums I can use this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,3,4,5,4,3,5,8,9], columns=["col1"] )

df['min'] = df.col1[(df.col1.shift(1) > df.col1) & (df.col1.shift(-1) > df.col1)]
```

As you can see I simply compare one cell with the 2 around it, if the next and previous cells are bigger that means I have a minimum, which is what I wanted. This works fine when I apply it to "col1" because all cells contain an integer.

But if I want to repeat the process applying this code to the min column I get an error. If you execute the code you will see in the "min" column there are only three cells with values: 2.0, 1.0, 3.0.

What I want is to compare the 1.0 to the 2.0 and the 3.0 which are the previous and next values to see if 1.0 is a global minimum or just a relative minimum.The problem is that I don't know how to jump through all those Nan.

In this numerical example the expected result is a new column filled with Nan everywhere except in one cell that contains the 1.0 number which is the absolute minimum, and corresponds to the 14 index position. This is just a very simple example, in reality I have a column with thousands of numbers so I expect to get many minimums still in the second iteration.

Basically I still need to compare the data even if there are Nan cells between them.

Can the shift function do it? What alternatives do I have?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some data sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: thanks jezrael for your suggestion, I have added a numerical example and more explanations, hopefully now it is more clear

Comment: Much better. Only last thing, is possible see expected output for verify solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `dropna()`:

```
df['min'] = df.col1.dropna()[(df.col1.dropna().shift(1) > df.col1.dropna()) & (df.col1.dropna().shift(-1) > df.col1.dropna())]
```

Another possible way to find minima is to use [`scipy.signal.argrelmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmin.html):

```
from scipy.signal import argrelmin
df['min'] = df.col1.dropna().iloc[argrelmin(df.col1.dropna().values)[0]]
```

Comment: I get this error:                                                                                                                                   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Comment: I ran this code with Python 3.7 & Pandas 1.0.3 - no such error occurred.

Comment: But have you applied it to the min column with Nan cells?                                                             I mean, it should be:                                                                                                                        df["min2"] = df.min.dropna() [ (df.min.dropna().shift(1) > df.min.dropna()) & (df.min.dropna().shift(-1) > df.min.dropna())]

Comment: NaNs in the 'min' column occur where there is no minimum which is expected. If you only want the values at minima you have to either save the results in another frame or series, or drop all rows where 'min' is NaN from the original dataframe.

Comment: It is strange, if I apply dropna () to the whole dataframe using this code df.dropna() I get a new dataframe without the Nan values, so there are no errors here. But if I apply it to a column, like you did, I get the error df.min.dropna() generates an error in my case. mac13k, I don't want to create a new dataframe, and I can't delete rows because they contain the original data and the first minimums. So it must be done inside this dataframe, I simply expect to get columns with more and more Nan cells.

Comment: OK, now I see the problem. `min` is the function, so if you mean the column you must refer to it as `df['min']`.

Comment: mac13k I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean, Can you show an example?

Comment: `min()` is the function that returns the minimal value ina dataframe or series, so if you write in your code `df.min` it refers to the function even though there is a column in your dataframe that is called 'min'. Thus you must use square brackets when you refer to the `min` column to avoid the confusion.

Comment: I had a very similar problem in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923343 ;)